# canvas size Increases the Bitmap Size android

Tags: android, android-canvas

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.raw.book11);
Canvas c = new Canvas(icon);
```

using this line of code for making canvas actually increases the size of the canvas(150x177) from the bitmap(100x118). If I use predefining the size of canvas, the bitmap gets cropped. Help please.
thanks.

Comment: Hi crack_addict, is that the actual code? When I run that code on Android 2.3.7 I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor". I guess the actual code you run looks slightly different? I would love to help you out but I need an accurate description of the problem to be able to provide an accurate answer. Maybe you could post a more complete code example?

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine with this equation:

```
event.getX()*3/2;
event.getY()*3/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

the system will automatically up-scale your image asset when you use it for a 'larger/higher' screen resolution/density if that particular asset is missing for that particular configuration (i.e. you're referencing an image on a hdpi device while that image is not present in the drawable-hdpi but only in raw drawable directory).

Note that scaling factor depends on device's screen density. In your case that seems to be 1.5.

EDIT: If not done yet, please check the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).